# Run Gunicorn service on DigitalOcean starting a Django project

Tags: django, linux, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I have the following `systemd` file at `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```sh
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn daemon for Django Project
Before=nginx.service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/serverapp
ExecStart=gunicorn --name=avesoft  --bind unix:/home/serverapp/gunicorn.socket --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py WebApp.wsgi:application
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=gunicorn
User=root
Group=www-data


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I manually change the directory to `/home/serverapp` and run `gunicorn --name=avesoft  --bind unix:/home/serverapp/gunicorn.socket --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py WebApp.wsgi:application` everything works fine and Nginx connects to my Django app through Gunicorn.

But by rebooting the server, I get Bad Gateway error that seems Gunicorn has not started working. I don't get what is the reason behind my service file not working.

Comment: does it work when you `sudo systemctl start gunicorn`?

Comment: @Mohd No it raises this error: `Reason: Exec format error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed that problem by providing the path for `gunicorn` :

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn daemon for Django Project
Before=nginx.service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/serverapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --name=avesoft  --bind unix:/home/serverapp/gunicorn.socket --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py WebApp.wsgi:application
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=gunicorn
User=root
Group=www-data


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```